# Optimising Laptop post ubuntu install

Tags: hard-drive, optimization

How can I check if windows has been completely removed from my laptop and that ubuntu 20.04 is booting from the same hdd and not my SanDisk USB flash?

Comment: please don't repost the same question. You can remove your "SanDisk USB flash" and see if Ubuntu boots without it ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gparted will give all the partition data, just like disk management in Windows, but more.

Open a terminal and install Gparted if not already installed:
`sudo apt install gparted`